# Getting image.map is not a function error while trying to render search list

Tags: reactjs, api, axios

When I try to .map the image i get from the parent component so as to render the images gotten from unsplash, i get a type error .map is not a function error.
    I have attached code for the problem.
    if error is solved it is meant to show the images from the search bar

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
        import axios from 'axios';
        import SearchBar from '../SearchBar/SearchBar';
        import ImageList from '../ImageList/ImageList';

        const API_KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_ACCESS_KEY;

        const SearchPage = () => {
          const [searchText, setSearchTerm] = useState('');
          const [image, setImage] = useState([]);

          const onInputChange = (e) => {
            setSearchTerm(e.target.value);
          };

          const fetchImages = () => {
            axios.get('https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos', {
              params: { query: searchText },
              headers: {
                Authorization: API_KEY,
              },

            })
              .then((data) => {
                setImage(data.data);
              });
          };
          console.log(image);
          const onSubmitHandler = (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            fetchImages();
          };

          return (
            <div>
              <SearchBar
                onSubmitHandler={onSubmitHandler}
                onInputChange={onInputChange}
                searchText={searchText}
              />

              <ImageList image={image} />

            </div>

          );
        };
        export default SearchPage;
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    /* eslint-disable jsx-a11y/alt-text */
    /* eslint-disable react/prop-types */
    import React from 'react';

    const ImageList = ({ image }) => {
      const imgs = image && image.map(img => (
        <img
          key={img.id}
          src={img.urls.regular}
        />
      ));
      return (
        <div>
          {' '}
          {imgs}
          {' '}
        </div>
      );
    };

    export default ImageList;
```

When I try to .map the image i get from the parent component so as to render the images gotten from unsplash, i get a type error .map is not a function error.
    I have attached code for the problem.
    if error is solved it is meant to show the images from the search bar

Comment: Try to `console.log` the image property

Comment: First of all, try removing the axios call, if no errors shows, this means the problem is in the response of that call. After, in axios call, add `console.log(data.data)` and add to your question what you see

Comment: Same as image an array from Unsplash

Answer (score 2):

Because you have an async call, you need to check it before `.map`.

```
  const imgs = image && image.map(img => (
    <img
      key={img.id}
      src={img.urls.regular}
    />
  ));
```

Or what you could do is set the default value of `image` to an array.

```
// default value as an array []
const ImageList = ({ image = [] }) => {
  const imgs = image.map(img => (
    <img
      key={img.id}
      src={img.urls.regular}
    />
  ));
  return (
    <div>
      {' '}
      {imgs}
      {' '}
    </div>
  );
};
```

This might not working depending on what is the default value of `image` in the parent component.

A better aproach would be setting the default value of `useState` to `[]`.

```
const [image, setImage] = useState([])
```

## Edit:

As said in the comments by OP

> I already had the image in the parent component initialized as an empty array.

So this means that when you do `setImage(data.data);`, `data.data` **isn't an array**.

Please check what is in `data.data` (maybe use `console.log`) and use the correct data you want to use `.map`.

Comment: I already had the image in the parent component initialized as an empty array.

Comment: @SImonHaddad please check my edit. If it was already initialized as an empty array, this means that `data.data` probably isn't an array. Please check it

Comment: I console.logged images and it is returning an array

Comment: No its still the same problem, it seems its from the function .map will paste code now

Answer (score 0):

A good practice for using map is to check the consistency that you will have an Array to map. Therefore, you can make a simple comparison to have a consistent array of your field =]

Change only your ImageList Component

```
const ImageList = ({ image }) => {

    const getImgs = () => (image.map(img => (
        <img
            key={img.id}
            src={img.urls.regular}
        />
    )));

    const imgs = typeof {} === 'object' && {}.length > 0 ? getImgs : <div>No images</div>;

    return (
        <div>
            {' '}
                {imgs}
            {' '}
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: It shows no images. So i console logged the typeof image in parent component and it shows object

Comment: Yes, I get it. In the case I answered only about how to get map consistency I ignored the render test. But if solved the problem is great, I will always be trying to help with what I can! Hugs!